# How do I update the useState variable BEFORE the user clicks a radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, radio-button

I have created a simple app [(click here for the code sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/employees-experiment-v17-stable-mhf3o?file=/src/App.js:680-705) that allows the user to input an employeeName, and then make selections to describe the employee.

When the user changes the employeeName (onClick from the input) it updates all of the radio button options. However, it does NOT update the "You have selected: ${employeeName} has made excellent progress" shown in red until they click another radio button, which forces the update.

How can I make it so that this line updates to show the new employeeName?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think is because when you first render the `Option` component the `isRadio` is undefined. That's why when you click on the radio you see the `You have selected: ....`

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you run `setIsRadio` only when radio button is pressed. In `Options.js` add a variable which will store selected value and update when `employeeName` changes.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsRadio(options[picked])   
}, [employeeName, options, picked]);
```

And for each input you also need to add:

```
onChange={() => {
  setIsRadio(options.excellent);
  // excellent, satisfactory, etc...
  setPicked('excellent');
}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, I'll be sure to give this a go today. Great solution, really helps me to understand a better way to use useEffect as well (still struggling to apply it in real-world projects) so that's great!

Answer (score -1):

Check this link and find difference in Options component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/employees-experiment-v17-stable-forked-pxj4q

When you update employeeName your Options component gets re-rendered as well.If user has selected any of the options from radio button then isRadio is set with hardcoded values from options array passed into Options component.And during re-render outputs that same hardcoded value instead of new updated EmployeeName.

For example:
1st time employeeName -> 'Harry'

If radio is checked,isRadio gets value as 'Harry has made excellent|poor|satisfactory  progress'.

2nd time employeeName gets updated -> 'Ram'

isRadio value from 1st time is 'Harry has made excellent|poor|satisfactory progress' which is not undefined and gets output in screen.

So,instead of setting value of isRadio to hardcoded string,store the key of object options and display value as options[isRadio] nexttime.

Comment: link dropping is considered bad practice at SO. Please include relevant information in your answer to improve quality and readability.